# Can't connect to mongodb via metabase

Tags: mongodb, metabase

I'm attempting to connect to a MongoDB using Metabase.

It's connecting through a SSH tunnel - these connection details are fine.

The error I'm getting from metabase is:

```
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 3000 ms while waiting for a server 
that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. 
Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=<redacted>:40206, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]
```

Can anyone decipher this message?

Comment: Similar problem? https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/6678 (At least same error - but it seems you are hosting elsewhere/which SSL??).

Comment: .... elsewhere/**with SSH tunnel**). Regarding SSH tunnel there’s this recent PR: https://github.com/metabase/metabase/pull/6970 Please share more version/config info on your environment.